# How to resolve 403 forbidden error while web-scrapping

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I am using pupeteer for web-scrapping in which first page load successfully even i can enter last name in the form and click the submit button also but when after navigation to next page it showing 403 forbidden error how to resolve that.

i tried this code but that did not work for me

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, // Set to true for headless mode
        defaultViewport: null, // You might need to adjust the viewport based on your website
      });
    
      const page = await browser.newPage();
    
      
        // Navigate to the form page
        await page.goto('https://registrantsearch.reco.on.ca/'); // Replace 'your_form_url_here' with the actual URL
    
        // Enter last name as "Malik"
        await page.type('#l-name', 'Malik');
    
        await Promise.all([page.click('#searchSalesperson'),page.waitForNavigation()])


         // Get the content of the next page
    const nextPageContent = await page.content();

    // Output or process the content as needed
    console.log('Content of the next page:', nextPageContent);
```

but i got output of last console is as below

```
Content of the next page: <html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2</center>








</body></html><!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --><!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --><!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --><!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --><!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --><!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to detect that you are scraping data.

#### How to avoid or mitigate errors like 403

- Use residential proxy
- Browser automation:

  - Try puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth(nodejs) or similiar library
  - Try both headless and non-headless mode
- API requests:

  - Use library support http2: such as got(nodejs) or httpx(python)
  - Simulate headers of current popular browsers
  - SSL fingerprints
  - Correct cookies: generated or copied
  - Valid token: generated or copied
- Rate limiting

As you use puppeteer, which belongs to browser automation in this case.

I could design a template using a vscode extension if needed.